# Java class with Interface member variable and member method behave differently. Please explain

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, class-members

Interface and a class `Number1`, later `Number2`, etc.
When I try to use member data inside method `add()`, it demands that I cast it first to class type.
However if I use member method inside method `add()`, it does not demand that I cast to class type.
Any explanation will be appreciated.

Code below attached.

---

```
    package mynums;
//Interface for all my number types, Number1, Number2 (not shown), etc
public interface NumberIF
{

    public int getNum();

    public void setNum(int numx);

    //I will have other types of numbers not just Number1.
    //I will have Number2, etc.
    public void add(NumberIF f1, NumberIF f2);
    public void print();
}


    package mynums;
//There will be other types of numbers Number2, Number3
//all doing these operations but different.
//This is just to test the concept.
//But I have a problem here.
public class Number1 implements NumberIF
{
    private int num;

    public Number1()
    {
        num = 1;
    }

    public Number1(int numx)
    {
        num = numx;
    }

    public int getNum()
    {
        return (num);
    }

    public void setNum(int numx)
    {
        num = numx;
    }

    public void add(NumberIF f1, NumberIF f2)
    {
        int numt;

        /**
         * Why to use member variables I must specify the type of class.
         * Why to use member method I do not have to specify type of class.
         */

        //numt = f1.num + f2.num;  ERROR

        // either one works
        //Why accessing member data is different from accessing member method.
        numt = ((Number1)f1).num + ((Number1)f2).num;
        numt = f1.getNum() + f2.getNum();

        num = numt;

    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        Number1 f1, f2, f3;

        f1 = new Number1(1);
        f2 = new Number1(2);
        f3 = new Number1(0);

        f3.add(f1, f2); // 1 + 2= 3
        f3.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: `f1` is of type `NumberIF` which does not have the member `private int num`.

Comment: @markspace Can you please verify my understanding and language.

I Can't do f1.num because (NumberIF type) does not have member variable num.
But once I cast it to Number1, I can do ((Number1) f1).num,
bc Number1 has .num.

I can do f1.getNum(), bc interface NumberIF has getNum() 
//even though it is only half cooked//, namely abstract unimplemented.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a *statically-typed* language.

Variables of static type `NumberIF` do not necessarily point to objects of type `Number1`, so those objects may not have the field `num`.

You only get to use the members of the static type (and its supertypes) of the variable.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I think I can't make your answer the "selected answer" possibly bc I have low reputation. Both answers helped. If you know how I can choose this as an answer you can send me private email so I know for next time.